# User irc inside of default Ubuntu 16.04 Server?

Tags: 16.04

I'm rather new to linux, however know my way around for the most part and ran into something strange today.

I was curious about all of the users on my linux box, and decided to cat the /etc/passwd file, and noticed a user called 'irc'

I have not installed anything on the server itself, and have only been running local commands, like top, ps, grep, cat, touch, things of that nature, nothing that would download and create that user.

Here is what the passwd looks like:

```
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I couldn't find much online about it, other than people saying if irc or ircd was installed, then it would create this user, however as mentioned above, I have not installed or downloaded anything.

Comment: Historical purposes most likely, see here... In the accepted answer, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197124/why-are-there-many-accounts-im-the-only-user

Comment: and yes, mostly historical reasons but it will also be security related.

Comment: The server is only a temporary server for learning purposes, the ip changes every hour, so its not of concern.

Answer (score 1):

Every Ubuntu system I have access to right now has this entry (and and accompanying entry `irc:x:39:` in `/etc/group` too).

As already has been stated that has mostly historical reasons. As you can see the directory `/var/run/ircd` doesn't even exist, the "user" cannot log in.  So it has no consequences, even on a production system.